# Realtime Database not responding

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to make a test to see if my database was working, but I don't know if the test not working, it was a problem of the test itself, or the connection.

I'm doing a flutter project using firebase, and in the logcat it says that the connection is successful.

these are the versions i'm using:

```
firebase_core: ^2.8.0
firebase_auth: ^4.3.0
cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5
provider: ^6.0.5
firebase_ui_auth: ^1.1.17
firebase_database: ^10.1.0
```

and this is the test i did:

```
void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  DatabaseReference _testRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("test");
  _testRef.set("Hello World ${Random().nextInt(100)}");
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}
```

I was expecting some connection to the database, but I only got the null value (so nothing was happening)

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your "test" path?

Comment: i was just following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/EXp0gq9kGxI?t=1030

Comment: If no data is written to the database, it may be that you didn't configure the database URL correctly. Check the log output of your app for errors/warnings, and/or try passing the database URL to `refFromURL`: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase/refFromURL.html